# Taylor expansion of a function defined by a sum.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I'm looking at a complex function defined as
$$f(z) = \sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r+1}\sin\left(\frac{pz}{r}\right)$$
and am looking to find its Taylor expansion about $z=0$. Presumably $p$ is some real number.

My instinct is to Taylor expand $\sin$ about $z=0$, then combine the sums. The only issue is that I have no idea how to combine sums nicely. Is this a decent approach, or is there a better way?

Comment: My first guess is that expanding and then reversing the order of summation leads to something nice

Comment: The problem with Taylor-expanding the sine and changing the order of summation is that you don't have absolute convergence. To get around that, you can write $$f(z) = \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{r+1} \frac{pz}{r} + \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{r+1}\Biggl(\sin \biggl(\frac{pz}{r}\biggr) - \frac{pz}{r}\Biggr)\,.$$ Then Taylor expansion in the second series leads to an absolutely convergent double series, so switching the order of summation is justified.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to find the derivatives of $f$ at zero. Clearly $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for all even $k$. If $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have
$$
f^{(k)}(0) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r+1} (p/r)^k = p^k\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{r^k}.
$$
If $k \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then we have
$$
f^{(k)}(0) = -\sum_{r=1}^\infty (-1)^{r+1} (p/r)^k = -p^k\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{r^k}.
$$
With that, we can write $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \eta(2n+1) p^{2n+1}z^{2n + 1}$, where
$$
\eta(k) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{r^k}.
$$
Note that this $\eta$ is known as the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).